# Is it possible to add keyboard and controller support to UI Toolkit buttons in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, ui-toolkit

I tried looking around online, but it doesn't seem like there's support for keyboard and controller inputs for buttons in the relatively new UI Builder for Unity.

From what I can tell, the old button system used Event Systems, but I wasn't able to get that to work for the UI Builder.
Will I need to use the old button system for my game if I really want that functionality?  Does anyone have any workarounds?